# Why is Multer req.file is undefined with this simple file upload?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Let me start off with :I've read through many similar topics, yet can't find the solution.

I just started a fresh react app, and copied the form from the express/multer documentation

```
      <form action="http://localhost:5001/app-dev/us-central1/api/upload" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div className="form-group">
            <input type="file" className="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file"></input>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Number of speakers" name="nspeakers"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Get me the stats!" className="btn btn-default"></input>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And I have a firebase function running locally with an express app.

```
const upload = multer({dest: './'})
app.post('/upload', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req: any, res: any) {
    console.log(req.file, req.body)
});
```

the request in the network call has these headers
[image: network call]

`req.file` is undefined when logging.

Does anyone see the missing piece?
Thanks a lot

ps. I use the `cors` middleware to resolve CORS issues (& GET calls are working)

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
const upload = multer({ dest: './' });

app.post('/app-dev/us-central1/api/upload', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.file, req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(5001, () => console.log('Server started at http://localhost:5001'));
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

  </div>

  <script type="text/babel">
    (function () {
      const e = React.createElement;

      class Upload extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <form action="http://localhost:5001/app-dev/us-central1/api/upload" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              <div className="form-group">
                <input type="file" className="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file"></input>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Number of speakers" name="nspeakers"></input>
                <input type="submit" value="Get me the stats!" className="btn btn-default"></input>
              </div>
            </form>
          )
        }
      }

      const domContainer = document.querySelector('#container');
      ReactDOM.render(e(Upload), domContainer);
    })()
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Server logs:

```
Server started at http://localhost:5001
{ fieldname: 'uploaded_file',
  originalname:
   'Stack Exchange personalized prediction data 2020-12-21.json',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/json',
  destination: './',
  filename: 'af7fc0ae20d3404ada7273792db07dc9',
  path: 'af7fc0ae20d3404ada7273792db07dc9',
  size: 99765 } [Object: null prototype] { nspeakers: '23' }
```

Client logs:

```
npx http-server -p 3001 -c-1Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:3001
  http://192.168.31.128:3001
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/65308716